# refresh parent page from jquery dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I want to refresh the parent page when I close my jQuery dialog.

this is the code I use for my dialog. I tried `top.opener.location` but it did not do nothing but put me on top of the page.

```
$("#dialog").dialog({ 
    height: 700, 
    width: 600, 
    closeOnEscape: true, 
    title: 'View', 
    close: function(event, ui){ 
        top.opener.location.reload(true); 
    }
}).dialog("open");
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The jQuery dialog opens on the same page, not in a new window. So simple refresh the current page:

```
location.reload(true);
```