# reload parent page from jQuery UI dialog box

Tags: jquery-ui

I have a gridview that is loaded in a jQuery UI dialog box. Both the dialog box and gridview are working great now.  But I was wondering how can I refresh the parent page when either clicking a button in the dialog box or closing the dialog box?

I tried this:

```
location.reload(true);
```

But it is only working in FF.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [refresh parent page from jquery dialog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1974499/refresh-parent-page-from-jquery-dialog)

Comment: That solution was accepted in the duplicate thread, not sure why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: yeah that's actually where I found it...it works fine in FF and Chrome but not IE9.

Comment: I see this method recommended in many places, and none of them mention that it doesn't work in IE.

Comment: I know...I will continue to look for a solution.  Thanks.

Comment: What about all the other methods in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624111/preferred-method-to-reload-page-with-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hate to answer my own question, but it's been 2 weeks and no answers.

After a bit of research, I decided to use simple javascript:

```
window.location.reload();
```

This worked in my situation.

Thanks