# ASP.NET Refresh Parent Page after Closing Modal Dialog Window

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have an ASP.NET page that launches a modal dialog window:

```
Dim sURL As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("PAYORS_Path") & "PayorCopy.aspx"
    lnkCopy.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:window.showModalDialog('" & sURL & "',null,'status:no;dialogWidth:375px;dialogHeight:550px;dialogHide:true;help:no;scroll:yes;center:yes');return false;")
```

The user can create new items in this modal window.  When the user clicks the Close button the modal dialog window is successfully closed, but the new items created do not appear on the parent page.  When the modal window is closed I would like the parent page to refresh to show the new items the user created.  Currently:

```
Private Sub btnClose_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventArgs) Handles btnClose.Click
    Dim strjscript As String = "<script language='javascript'>self.close();</script>"
    LtClose.Text = strjscript
End Sub
```

I have tried adding to this script:

```
window.opener.location.reload(true);
```

But then when I test I get an error that says "Unable to get value of the property 'location': object is null or undefined."

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the old modal dialog window, try [jQuery Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) because it behaves just like a modal but keeps you in the same window. Therefore it's is easily refreshed with the following code:

```
location.reload(true);
```

For more information, check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1974499/refresh-parent-page-from-jquery-dialog) question here at SO.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

That would be because there is no 'opener' :)
Location is method of the window object so you can even treat it as global is most cases. Any of those should work:

```
window.location.reload(true);
```

or:

```
location.reload(true);
```

**EDIT** Yeah I just noticed where you put that script.. if it's in the click handle inside the modal..then 'window' there is really a different one - it's modal after all! Try adding it **directly** after the code opening modal window - the script execution will be blocked until the modal returns, so you can so something like this:

```
var shouldReloadPage = window.showModalDialog('" & sURL & "',null,'status:no;dialogWidth:375px;dialogHeight:550px;dialogHide:true;help:no;scroll:yes;center:yes');
if(shouldReloadPage){
window.location.reload(true);
}
return false;
```

This is still inside the click handler ofc, just showing in code block for easier reading.

Comment: That eliminates the error I was getting, but the parent page still does not refresh.

Comment: See the edit above... you should be reloading the page in the actual page's code, best place directly after opening the modal.

Comment: I added:

    lnkCopy.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:var(shouldReloadPage = window.showModalDialog('" & sURL & "',null,'status:no;dialogWidth:375px;dialogHeight:550px;dialogHide:true;help:no;scroll:yes;center:yes');if(shouldReloadPage){window.location.reload(true);}return false;)"


And now the modal dialog window won't launch at all - when I click nothing happens.

Comment: There's an extra bracket after var in the first line (and potentially one in the last just after 'return false;').. other than that always check the browser console for hints on errors.

Comment: Ah, yes.  Not sure how that happened, but I have updated to:

    lnkCopy.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:var shouldReloadPage = window.showModalDialog('" & sURL & "',null,'status:no;dialogWidth:375px;dialogHeight:550px;dialogHide:true;help:no;scroll:yes;center:yes');if(shouldReloadPage){window.location.reload(true);}return false;")


The modal dialog window now launches successfully.  However, when I close it the parent page does not refresh.